# Arranging subfolders within view folder in mvc projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, directory-structure

I have a MVC project where the main View folder is subdivided into different folders. These different folders are named by their corresponding purpose, such as;

[image]

I have some partial views which are being shared across multiple views, but special to each subfolder. So as an example, a partial view within the `Purchase` folder is being shared only by the views stands into `Purchase` subfolder. My question is, how should I structure my folders to keep it simple? Would it be a good practice to create a sub-subfolder under each subfolder and name it as `PartialViews` or is it better to keep these partial views stay with other views one under the other without creating another subfolder?

I am waiting for your advices, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Area concept in MVC
refer this..

[enter link description here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc)